# Resize divs width and height on browser resize with CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a large div containing an image. I want that image to shrink or expand depending on the browsers window height/width. I can achieve this horizontally by using `width: 100%` but the image div disappears entirely if I set height 100%.

I realise you must set BODY and HTML to have a height and width of 100% and I have done this to no avail.

The image appears fine if I give it a hard-coded pixel height, but I would want this to shrink if the browser becomes smaller.

Would anyone know the correct way of achieving this, preferably with just CSS?

My code is:

```
HTML, BODY {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#imagecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(image.jpg);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Works fine here.. http://jsfiddle.net/N3MaJ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/dangoodspeed/N3MaJ/1/  Not sure if I understand the question 100%, but I think the line you may want is

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Ah yes, that worked. I also had a #wrapper that I should have set to 100% x 100% as well